# How to make Drupal instance store the files as "public:"?

Tags: files

I am trying to use the http://drupal.org/project/gdoc_field module but it is not working as appearently Google can't access them... I am uploading them from my machine by using the browse functionality.

How do I make the files uploaded via this Field type public, so they are accessible by Google and therefore display in an iframe?

Comment: Are you using a public filesystem or private? Looks like it needs to be a public one, according to the documentation on the module's page: *...your system must store the files as "public:".*

Comment: I've left the "File directory" text field blank.
(Optional subdirectory within the upload destination where files will be stored. Do not include preceding or trailing slashes. This field supports tokens.)
What should I set it to instead? @jerdiggity

Comment: In admin/config/media/file-system I've got "Public file system path" set to sites/default/files @jerdiggity